# In CakePHP 3, following the tutorial, why does the login form fail silently?

Tags: cookies, cakephp-3.0

Here is some puzzling behavior:  Following the CakePHP 3 tutorial (approximately), I create a login form and set up AuthComponent to authenticate using the form input.  I also set up AuthComponent to authorize.  But when I submit the login form, the page appears to reload as if nothing happened.  Why?

Additional detail (which turns out to be relevant): I installed CakePHP in the root of the domain, and I am not using mod_rewrite.  I followed the instructions in config/app.php to disable mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently ran into this bug and spent quite a bit of time working it out. It presents as a problem with session persistence.  Whatever session handler I tried, session data did not persist across page loads.  The observable behavior that triggered my investigation was as above; AuthComponent, while it would properly recognize a user and "save" it using setUser(), was unable to "remember" the saved user on the next page load.  Put another way, this looks like the login form is failing silently.  This behavior turned out to be a symptom of the cookie failing to be loaded on the subsequent page load.  AuthComponent (by way of Cake\Network\Session) would write the newly-recognized user to the cookie, but not load the cookie on the next page load, causing it to appear as though my login screen simply re-rendered.

I traced this problem to the 'cookiePath' setting under the Session group in config/app.php.  It seems that with the default setting, the cookie's path was being set to "/webroot/".  In my setup, I am not using mod_rewrite, and so my URLs look like, e.g., /index.php/users/login.  With a path of /webroot/, the cookie was not being recognized and loaded properly.  Therefore, the subsequent page load (1) could not read a current session ID, (2) could not find any previously-stored session data (no matter how the session data was stored), (3) could not identify a current user, and (4) punted me back to the login page, sans any Flash error message.

I don't know if this problem goes away if you are using mod_rewrite, and I realize [there has been extensive discussion about this on GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/4275).  I'm not sure who is Officially Right in that thread.  However, in case this is helpful to anyone with a similar configuration to me, I resolved this problem by setting 'cookiePath' => '/' in the 'Session' key within config/app.php.

Comment: I would consider the path being set to `/webroot/` when there is no `/webroot/` in the base URL a possible bug - so if this problem persists even with a recent dev-snapshot, then you may want to report that.

Comment: @ben thanks for your post. it saved me. 

After setting cookiePath to '/', my session was not working but after some time it started working. Could you please tell us the reason for this?

Comment: @FaiyazAlam I'm not sure what the underlying issue is based on the information you supplied, but it's possible you had some unexpired cookies in your web browser that were persisting bad session data.

Comment: @BenBirney thanks. Now I have new issue that I want to remove index.php from url. I have searched for this many times but it did not work.
Could you please tell me that is it possible to remove index.php if I am not using mod_rewrite module? I have bluehost shared hosting.